# how do get the account id when clicking submit button then display the client details on the label?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

```
    // submit button
    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");

    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        //label that used to display the name, house number, postcode
    JLabel lblNameDisplay = new JLabel("-");

    JLabel lblHouseNoDisplay = new JLabel("-");

    JLabel lblPostCodeDisplay = new JLabel("-");

    Object accID = e.getSource();
    //when clicking the submit, should get account id and display the client details on the label
    if(accID==btnSubmit){


        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have two btnSubmit variables

```
JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");     <-----

btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");    <-----
```

If you do `if(accID==btnSubmit)` - Which one are you using?

But anyway,

The actionListener is bound to your `btnSubmit` button so `getSource()` is going to return the `btnSubmit` object.

Comment: the first one because it should used to get account id and display the client details.

Comment: yeah, this is why i can't get account id. do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry, what is account id?  I can not see from your code.  The actionListener is bound to your btnSubmit button so getSource() is going to return the btnSubmit object.

Answer (score 0):

Any code within

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { ... }
```

will be executed when clicking the "Submit" button because you created an anonymous action listener specifically for use with the button (hence use of anonymous inner class).

Therefore, all you really need to put in the actionPerformed(...) method would be the assignment of the new labels (assuming that they already exist or you got them somewhere).

e.g.

```
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        lblExampleLabel.setText("This is what the label will become after clicking the button");
    }
});
```

Comment: JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {                    
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    lblNameDisplay.setText(getfamilyName());
    lblHouseNoDisplay.setText(gethouseNumber());
    lblPostCodeDisplay.setText(getpostCode());

} 
}
});

Comment: before clicking submit button, i need to insert the account id only can display the client details like the name, house and house number on the label..

Comment: I guess what you are trying to say is that you need to get the details pertaining to the account id when pressing the submit button. In that case, do you logic of grabbing those information in the actionPerformed(...) method, THEN set the labels.

If you are trying to access account ID, then note that it should either be a class variable or declared final so that it is accessible within the anonymous inner class. [Anonymous inner class variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html#accessing)